# Using Jquery, how pass a table to another page when press tag <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to pass a page within the main page, and a page that want to pass it contains the tag  ,When it is pressed working to pass another page within the main page.

I've put jquery on the main page, but it did not work, but I put it on the tag page, But it worked on the first row only.
This jquery when press tag

```
$( "#update_range" ).click(function() {
    var testing2 = this.name;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update_form.php",
      data: { testing1:testing2  },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#inner_content").append(data+"<br/>");                    
      },
    });
});
```

And this is tag ,I have many of them in the table and this is one of them, they are have same id :

```
 <td><a href="#update" id="update_range" name="<?php echo $row1['id_testing']; ?>">Update Test</a></td>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle showing `innre_content` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"#update_range"` is an [ID selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors). An ID [must be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) in a document.

Presumably you have given each row the same ID, which is invalid HTML (use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)) and causes JavaScript to find only the first element with that ID.

Use a [class selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) (which starts with a `.`) and [class attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) instead.

---

The `name` attribute on the `<a>` element is obsolete. You are using it for what you should be using the `id` attribute for (and since you aren't actually trying to link anywhere, you should probably be using a `<button>` instead of an `<a>` too).

Comment: Thank you very much this helps me
I wish you a happy life @Quentin